# WordPress Redirection Plugin Stripping "utm_" parameters on redirect

Tags: wordpress, redirect, utm

I'm using the WordPress Redirection plugin to try to create redirects that maintain their query parameters after redirect. I've setup all my redirects using the “Ignore & pass parameters to the target” setting in Redirection and it's working for all parameters except “utm_” parameters. URLs with “utm_” parameters have those parameters stripped on redirect.

**Here's as an example:**

https://www.oliveandcompany.com/test is set to redirect to https://www.oliveandcompany.com/about with “Ignore & pass parameters to the target” set. This base redirect is functioning correctly.

**The following URL with a generic parameter redirects correctly to the about page and maintains the parameter:**
https://www.oliveandcompany.com/test/?param=test

**This URL with a "utm_" parameter redirects correctly to the about page but strips the parameter**:
https://www.oliveandcompany.com/test/?utm_source=test

I’ve tested this issue with Redirection across three different sites and the results are the same everywhere. I’ve also tried turning off all other plugins and still no luck. I've tried many different parameter variations and it comes down to just the "utm_" parameters being stripped.

Any ideas on how to maintain the “utm_” parameter on redirect?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who runs across this, the problem ([explained and resolved here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/only-utm_source-being-stripped-on-redirect/)) has to do with CDNs and hosting providers (Fastly and Flywheel, though it also applies to WP Engine) stripping 'utm' and sometimes 'glcid' params in order to improve caching performance. You can read more about this on [WP Engine's post from Feb 21, 2020 here](https://wpengine.com/support/utm-gclid-variables-caching/).